# determine if a line segment is within a polygon

Tags: python, geometry, polygon

I am trying to find out if a given line segment consisting of two or more points is inside a polygon here is a drawing to help capture the idea:
[picture to help visualize the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oef1.png)

All I found on the internet was a code that accepted a line passing through a polygon (could be only inside or just passing through a polygon) not exclusively inside a polygon here is the code mentioned:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry
import descartes

circle = shapely.geometry.Point(5.0, 0.0).buffer(10.0)
clip_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[-9.5, -2], [2, 2], [3, 4], [-1, 3]])
clipped_shape = circle.difference(clip_poly)

line = shapely.geometry.LineString([[-10, -5], [15, 5]])
line2 = shapely.geometry.LineString([[-10, -5], [-5, 0], [2, 3]])

print 'Blue line intersects clipped shape:', line.intersects(clipped_shape)
print 'Green line intersects clipped shape:', line2.intersects(clipped_shape)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(*np.array(line).T, color='blue', linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round')
ax.plot(*np.array(line2).T, color='green', linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round')
ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(clipped_shape, fc='blue', alpha=0.5))
ax.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not familiar with `shapely.geometry`, going to need to look at that. The hard way: check both segment endpoints to see if they're in the polygon.  If they are, check each segment of the polygon to see if it intersects with the test segment.  Any intersection is a fail.

Comment: If you knew that the polygon was convex, simply checking that both endpoints of the segment are inside it would be sufficient.  To handle the concave case, you'd additionally need to check that the segment doesn't intersect any of the edges of the polygon.

Comment: the concave situation is the one that i want to solve. but i dont really know how to actually code it without making it extremely slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if the segment completely lies within the polygon you can follow these two-step procedure:

1. Look for segment-polygon intersections. If intersections are found then the segment does not lie within the polygon and the procedure stops here.

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, Polygon

point_a = Point(7, 2)
point_b = Point(10, 6)

segment = LineString([point_a, point_b])
polygon = Polygon([(1, 0), (4, 1), (5, 4), (3, 5), (3, 2)])
polygon_ext = LineString(list(polygon.exterior.coords))
intersections = polygon_ext.intersection(segment)
```

2. If no intersection is found, then we need to check if the segment is actually lying within the polygon. So let's pick one point from the segment and verify if it is contained within the polygon.

```py
if intersections.is_empty:
    if polygon.contains(point_a):
        print("The segment completely lies within the polygon.")
    else:
        print("The segment does not lies within the polygon.")
else:
    print("Segment-polygon intersections are found.")
```

For this case, no intersection is found but the line is outside the polygon, as you can see in the image below:
[image]

If we modify the line, for instance:

```py
point_a = Point(2, 3)
point_b = Point(10, 6)
```

polygon-segment intersections are found (see image below):
[image]

If:

```py
point_a = Point(2, 0.5)
point_b = Point(3.3, 4)
```

again intersections are found:

[image]

Finally, for the case:

```py
point_a = Point(2, 3)
point_b = Point(10, 6)
```

the segment completely lies within the polygon as per image below:
[image]

Comment: Much better....

Comment: That is a great solution much faster than just looping through every edge of a polygon and looking for intersections. This new solution reduced the time per execution by 34%. Thanks.

Comment: Would this run faster if you did the endpoint check before the intersection check?

Comment: Am I allowed to extend on the question maybe add something because i just realized that there is more to this problem than just exteriors of polygons i also deal with polygons with holes so i need a way to find if the line is truly in the polygon not just in one of the holes or passing through a hole of the polygon here is a picture to clarify: (https://i.imgur.com/W6aWoQT.png)

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to repeat the procedure above multiple times, i.e. you have a polygon with two holes in it; these two holes can be considered as polygons as well, so, using the procedure above, the line is truly within the polygon if it is within the polygon (the external contour) but outside the two polygons acting as holes. (internal contours).

Comment: ...it should be pretty straightforward to implement. I do not know the overall complexity of the problem, but I would just define a function that returns a boolean and that encapsulates the procedure above. So the line is truly within the polygon if the function returns True for the outer contour AND False for all the other polygons representing the inner contours.

Comment: @Learner is the polygon with a hole coded as a single list of points or two lists of points?

Comment: the polygon itself is in a list and the holes are in separate list where the items in the list are individual holes ex .  poly = [[0,0],[0,10],[10,10],[10,0],[0,0]]          inners = [ [[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,4],[4,4],[4,3],[3,3]]]